# gscan2pdf on Linux Mint: Scanner works only as root

Tags: linux, linux-mint, scanner, scanning

I'm trying to get a Brother ADS-2200 scanner to work with gscan2pdf on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon. **The scanner is recognized and works with Document Scanner without any issue.** However, when opening gscan2pdf, it doesn't:

Scanner plugged in:

- When starting from Menu, the GUI opens and closes again without any info.
- When opening via command line (`gscan2pdf`), the GUI asks me to restore a crashed session, then gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
- When opening from command line as SU, (`sudo gscan2pdf`), the GUI asks me to restore a crashed session, then gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Scanner not plugged in:

- When opening via menu, GUI opens and displays an error message `Error opening device: opening device 'BrotherADS2200:libusb:001:008': Access to resource has been denied`. After that, plugging in the scanner and rescanning for devices does not list the device (but others, which work).
- When opening from command line as SU, (`sudo gscan2pdf`) opens the GUI. Sometimes it recognizes the scanner upon rescanning for devices, sometimes it doesn't. If it does recognize the scanner, the device works.

It's really confusing, but it seems like the only remotely possible way to get the scanner it work is to use the SU approach multiple times while hoping the rescanning works.

Additional info:

- Using `sane-find-scanner` (no sudo) list the scanner `found possible USB scanner...`
- Using `scanimage -L` (no sudo) lists the scanner `device BrotherADS2200:libusb:001:020 is a Brother ADS2200 USB scanner`
- Using `scanimage -T` (no sudo) passes all
- Sane Backends: 1.1.1-debian; backend version 1.1.1
- gscan2pdf version 2.12.8-0 via ppa1jammy

Answer (score 0):

start gscan2pdf with device :

```
$ gscan2pdf --device BrotherADS2200:libusb:001:028
```

Get the device from

```
$ scanimage -L
device `BrotherADS2200:libusb:001:028' is a Brother ADS2200 USB scanner
```

that works for me.